# How to join twice times to another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I got this code:

```
        SELECT
            topics.id,
            topics.id_first,
                            posts.id_first
          FROM topics
        LEFT
          JOIN posts
            ON posts.id = topics.id_first_msg
```

My intention, is to do something like this:

```
        SELECT
            topics.id,
            topics.id_first,
                            posts.id_first,
                            posts.id_last
          FROM topics
        LEFT
          JOIN posts
            ON posts.id = topics.id_first_msg
        LEFT
          JOIN posts
            ON posts.id = topics.id_last_msg
```

But, when I try to do Left Join twice, I get an error. Which is the correct way then? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide aliases for the table you're joining more than once:

```
SELECT
    topics.id,
    topics.id_first,
    p1.id_first,
    p2.id_last
FROM topics
LEFT JOIN posts p1 ON p1.id = topics.id_first_msg
LEFT JOIN posts p2 ON p2.id = topics.id_last_msg
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to alias the second left join;

```
    SELECT
        topics.id,
        topics.id_first,
                        posts.id_first,
                        posts2.id_last
      FROM topics
    LEFT
      JOIN posts
        ON posts.id = topics.id_first_msg
    LEFT
      JOIN posts AS posts2
        ON posts2.id = topics.id_last_msg
```

Answer (score 0):

The posts table is ambiguous. 
First off - do you really need to join twice? Can't you just do this:

```
    SELECT
        topics.id,
        topics.id_first,
        posts.id_first,
        posts.id_last,
        posts.id_first,
        posts.id_last
      FROM topics
    LEFT
      JOIN posts
        ON posts.id = topics.id_first_msg
```

Second - if you really have to join twice - give the posts table two different aliases (you'll still need to edit the selected columns)